# Delphi 2010 lock the menu at the top?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Every so often, I accidentally move the panels at the top of my IDE.

I.e. I move the file menu some where I don't want, and then have to move it back again, then I will need to rearrange the icons below.

Are there any neat tricks for locking this top panel so I never need to accidentally move my icons and menus again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nobody could answer this, but I found out if you install CNPack (CnWizards) you will get the option of checking "lock toolbar"

http://www.cnpack.org/showdetail.php?id=689&lang=en

you also get many other things, you might want to disable, like show taborder on form etc etc